# can I affich 2 items from diffrent adapter in the same listview?

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter, baseadapter

I have one Listview and I have 2 items layouts every item from diffrent adapter and i would to display this items in the same listView but in difrrent position ,is That possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easy achived that by making custom adapter and custom view.

Example: [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: Thanks, this helps me